# Installing an upgraded display in Laptop

Tags: display, hardware-rec

I recently have acquired an MSI GL62M 7RDX laptop. Now everything is fine, except for one thing. The screen is the biggest piece of garbage ever to walk this earth.

I have a lot of experience with desktop PC building, however very little with Laptop modification. The crux of my question is, is it possible to upgrade this display? What do I need to know and find out exactly in order to get a display that would be compatible? I am not looking for display recommendations, simply the method of choosing a display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are only two types of display can be used on GL62M 7RDX according to official specification

15.6" FHD (1920x1080), Wide-View

15.6" FHD (1920x1080), IPS-Level

If you want to upgrade display, you need to consult MSI support or let them help you to upgrade.

Comment: Can you please advise the URL of that information? I was unable to find such info. And the Wide-view might be what I need, since I believe I have the IPS-Level

Comment: https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GL62M-7RDX/Specification